# Select case statement in Crystal report formula

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am using the following formula field in crystal report to go to specific URL. but when i click the field it always goes to default statement **the code
goes from here**

```
select {USP_GetSpecificAccountLedger.InvoiceNo}
case totext({USP_GetSpecificAccountLedger.JVID}):
"http:"+"//"+"localhost:60470/AdminPages/AccountPayable.aspx"
case totext({USP_GetSpecificAccountLedger.ACCOUNTID}):
"http:"+"//"+"localhost:60470/AdminPages/ViewManualJournal.aspx?id="+ToText({USP_GetSpecificAccountLedger.JVID})
Default :
"http://localhost:60470/AdminPages/Vendor.aspx";
```

Need a bit help. :(

Comment: are you trying hyper link functionality?

Comment: yup that what i am trying..functionally

Answer (score 0):

In this case you shouldn't write inside a formula field instead you need to go to the

Format Field ---> Hyper link tab --> radio button `A Website on Internet`

There in `X-2` you need to click and write your formula there.

I guess your code is in `Basic Syntax` so select that and paste this code.

```
select {USP_GetSpecificAccountLedger.InvoiceNo}
case totext({USP_GetSpecificAccountLedger.JVID}):
"http:"+"//"+"localhost:60470/AdminPages/AccountPayable.aspx"
case totext({USP_GetSpecificAccountLedger.ACCOUNTID}):
"http:"+"//"+"localhost:60470/AdminPages/ViewManualJournal.aspx?id="+ToText({USP_GetSpecificAccountLedger.JVID})
Default :
"http://localhost:60470/AdminPages/Vendor.aspx";
```

I haven't checked the syntax of the code and you need to check before using.

Comment: i have already done this thing. but didn't get any accurate results. what i need... :(

Comment: what are you missing? is the hyper link not getting opened?

Comment: yeah the first case and the second case is not getting opened